# Criar uma referência do objeto no seu próprio método

Tags: c#, .net, string

## Problema

Eu quero pegar os últimos dígitos desta `string`, então eu utilizei o método `Substring()`, porem eu tive que usar a variável "numero" mais uma vez dentro do método `Substring()`.

```
string numero = "123456789";
string final = numero.Substring(numero.Length - 4);
Console.Write(final);
```

Existe alguma forma de referenciar a variável `numero` de forma genérica no seu próprio método? Algo como:

```
string final = numero.Substring(reference.Length - 4);
```

> Usei a palavra "reference" apenas como um exemplo, tenho ciência que
>   da forma que esta não vai funcionar.

## Porque quero isso

Da forma como esta é bem simples para utilizar a variável número, porém no código no qual eu preciso realizar este procedimento a variável que estou a usando está em uma cadeia de métodos e submétodos, assim a referencia deixa o código confuso. Como paliativo eu fiz o seguinte:

```
string numero = referenciaMuitoGrandeBlaBla;
string final = numero.Substring(numero.Length - 4);
Console.Write(final);
```

Já ajuda, porem não queria usar desta forma, já que pode existir uma forma de referenciar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie um método de extensão para criar seu `Substring` customizado, dentro desse método você implementa a lógica que quiser. Para criar um método de extensão precisamos criar uma classe estática e métodos estáticos que possuam a palavra chave `this` que irá referencia o nosso objeto atual, segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
namespace ExemploExtensao
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string SubstringCustomizado(this string texto, int length)
        {
            //Implemente a lógica que desejar. 
            //this string texto se refere ao objeto que chamar esse método
            return texto.Substring(texto.Length - length);
        }
    }
```

Para utilizar esse método basta referenciar o namespace e chamar da mesma forma que você chama o método `Substring`:

```
using ExemploExtensao    
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string teste = "0123456789";

        //Quando chamar seu SubstringCustomizado, a variável teste irá ser o 
        //parâmetro this do método, assim você não precisa passar como 
        //parâmetro conforme sua pergunta
        Console.WriteLine(teste.SubstringCustomizado(4));
    }
}
```

Mais informações sobre métodos de extensão você pode verificar na documentação da Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: Interessante, vou da +1, mas ainda não é a resposta que eu estou procurando, porque eu queria realmente a referência pela facilidade, desta forma que você fez é bacana, mas vai da mais trabalho do que colocar em uma variável antes do processo como referência.

Answer (score 3):

No C# 8 é possível fazer assim:

```
Write("123456789"[^4..]);
```

Isto é uma faixa ([*range*](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/ranges.md)).

Enquanto isso o que você deseja é ter um método chamado `Right()`, ou seja, um método que pegue os caracteres que está à direita. De fato a única forma de fazer isso é usar a variável duas vezes, então para evitar esta duplicidade na sintaxe precisa criar uma abstração (a arte perdida dos programadores). A forma mais interessante de se fazer isto é criar um método de extensão para `String` em `System`, assim em todas as *strings* este método estará disponível como se fosse um método normal do tipo:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("123456789".Right(4));
    }
}

namespace System {
    public static class StringExtensions {
        public static string Right(this string text, int length) => text.Substring(text.Length - length);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8TOa9D). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XTWzYQ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Right.cs).